# Compare/match two columns using approximate string matching (fuzzy string matching, levenshtein)

Tags: c#, hashtable, levenshtein-distance

First of let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. The application that I'm making should have the ability to compare two columns of two different tables with eachother. So every cell of the column from the first table should be linked to the best matching cell from the column of the second table. So you would get something like this:

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [modelbouwforum.nl](http://foto.modelbouwforum.nl/images/2014/11/03/Levenshtein_match.png))</sub>

This can easily be achieved by using the Levenshtein's algorithm. So I wrote a test program in c# to see if I can recreate the same results as the image is showing us. I made two array's, one containing the first column of the image and one containing the second column of the image. Every cell of the first column is compared to every cell of the second column, so that means I get 4 iterations on every cell (16 in total). The highest match (the one with the lowest levenshtein distance) of the second column is then linked to the cell of the first column.

The problem:
Let say we have two large columns with 100K rows each, this should get some serious performance issues. Because every cell from the first column need to be matched to every cell of the second column to get the highest possible match, so you have to iterate 100K * 100K = 10 billion times. So I have to create something to avoid iterating 10 billion times.

I did some research about where levenshtein could be used and came across this: http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/VasileTopac/fuzzy-hash-map/4. I'm wondering if I am able to create something like the guy did in the link?

Some things to consider:

- In such large columns there could be multiple matches on a single cell(the user need to chose the right one). So that means you can't
  exclude previously matched cells from the current search in order to bring down the iteration.
- In the example the matching/comparison is only done on two columns, however in the future I like to compare a single column from table 1
  to all the columns from table 2 (less work for the user). This will be even more time expensive as you can expect.

NOTE:
I'm only using c# for 4 months right now, I'll hope someone can provide me a good starting point (I prefer not get a fully working answer, I rather want to do some research myself to learn from it as well). Thanks for the understanding. English is not my native language, so please feel free to edit my post.

Comment: I assume "@us" prefix can be simply dropped (or symbols ignored) then I'd first try to **cluster** entries in one table (for example "PUSH_BUTTON", "PUSH-BUTTON" and "PUSH BUTTON" will all become "PUSHBUTTON". Symbols can be dropped and numbers will be separators (yes, pretty naive so far!). Now you may extract a **fingerprint** (it may simply be longest word, for now). It'll be your hash key.

Comment: Now for each entry on 2nd table you don't have to calculate distance to vs each one in the first table: simply apply clustering and then calculate distance vs fingerprints. Set will be greatly reduced and then you can calculate distance vs each item in the subset (for example FUSE 1A, FUSE 2A, FUSE 5A, FUSE 10A will all have key "FUSE").

Comment: To summarize: if your first table has 100K entries and you reduce them to 1000 clusters (each one with 100 entries) then you'll calculate distance only 1000 (each cluster) + 100 (each entry in selected cluster). 1100 Levenshtein's calculations (the slow part) instead of 100000 (around 90% gain but you have to add time for cluster calculation). Of course don't forget all these stuff MUST be cached so clustering is first table is calculated once and reused for each entry in 2nd table. Finally (including your original algorithm) this is pretty good to be parallelized!!!

Comment: You definitely need to sanitize those values before trying to match; stripping special characters would probably do wonders in this case. If you have known prefixes, or know that `@.*_` will always be a prefix, you can remove that as well.

Comment: P.S. for fingerprint function you can also use a very very very VERY poor string hashing function (more collisions you have and better it is). Comparison may be done vs. 1st and 2nd best fingerprint matches (and eventually vs all table if you can't find a _decent_ match, in case you can statistically _judge_ (somehow) Levenshtein's distances.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I understand what you are trying to achieve here. That would be a neat way to do it! However I think I'll still have some problems with it. For instance, our tables also have some unique product numbers (e.g. 101031153, 101022616, 101031174, etc...). With those product numbers I don't see how I could cluster it to chunks to improve the performance. The only way I think of to cluster product numbers is cluster on each 1000th number (e.g. 10103**1**174, 10103**1**153, 10103**1**596). I will take a dive in this subject, thanks!

Comment: @ssube Yes I forgot to mention I already made that particular function. The user can execute deletions, insertions, substitutions on the table before a match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to come up with some assumption that always holds true about the matching that can segment it into smaller chunks like:

> The first capital alpha character in table 1 must match the first capital alpha character in table 2

You may be able to find some valid assumption that will allow you to pre-process the values into another column:

```
FirstAlpha1   FirstAlpha2
===========   ===========
P             C
S             F
C             P
F             S
```

Then you could do a simple sort and join (exact match) on this extra value to divide the solution into smaller chunks.